# Does the derivative of an implicit function have critical points for both y and x?

Tags: calculus

Just like the title says.

This a generalized question because it wasn't clarified in my Calc 1 class and I am working with an implicit function right now. I *assume* the answer is **yes** because I can find points in the derivative where f'(x)=0 in regard to f(x) and x... but I wan't to be safe and double check.

I tried googling this and searching on math.stackexchange.com but I have come up short on a definite answer. Feel free to point me in the right direction online. Otherwise I don't mind elaboration from someone on the subject to help my further understanding.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, take as a simple example a circle centered at the origin.

$$ x^2+y^2=r^2 $$

One finds that

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}=0 $$

at points $(0,\pm r)$ where the horizontal tangents lie and that

$$ \frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{y}{x}=0 $$

at points $(\pm r,0)$ where the vertical tangents lie.